# Calculation based on previous row in same column and previous row in another column in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to calculate NoofEventsInQueue Column as below in power Bi. `157` is the total no of Events

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a calculated column:

```
NumberOfEventsInQueue = 
IF ( 
    ISBLANK ( Table1[NoOfEventsAtATime] ),
    BLANK(),
    CALCULATE ( 
        SUM ( Table1[NoOfEventsAtATime] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            Table1[Ref_Time] >= EARLIER ( Table1[Ref_Time] )
        )
    )
)
```

If you have blank rows in the middle of your `NoOfEventsAtATime` column, and still want a value returned on your calculated column, you could use something like:

```
NumberOfEventsInQueue = 
VAR TimeMin = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MIN ( Table1[Ref_Time] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            NOT ISBLANK ( Table1[NoOfEventsAtATime] )
        )
    )
VAR TimeMax = 
    CALCULATE ( 
        MAX ( Table1[Ref_Time] ),
        FILTER ( 
            ALL ( Table1 ),
            NOT ISBLANK ( Table1[NoOfEventsAtATime] )
        )
    )
VAR Output = 
    IF ( 
        Table1[Ref_Time] >= TimeMin && Table1[Ref_Time] <= TimeMax,
        CALCULATE ( 
            SUM ( Table1[NoOfEventsAtATime] ),
            FILTER ( 
                ALL ( Table1 ),
                Table1[Ref_Time] >= EARLIER ( Table1[Ref_Time] )
            )
        ),
        BLANK()
    )
RETURN Output
```

Comment: It worked, Is it possible to remove the value "157" from first 3 rows? Actually I have to plot Rundown in area chart. So, It should be "0" or blank untill the process starts

Comment: It is giving blank if row is blank in between as well. Anyway good help :)

Comment: Answer edited once again, to return values where intermediate rows are blank.

Comment: Excellent! Now getting as required. Many Thanks